# Making browser send requests to specific port

Tags: browser, tcp, netcat

Trying to learn about networking I created a tcp connection , e.g:

```
$ nc -p 12345 google.com 80
```

now if I send GET requests everything is fine and I can see all packets in Wireshark.

But if I want to try it in my browser and type into my browser bar

```
localhost:12345
```

it refuses to connect and is in fact not even sending any packets. ( with the TCP connection still being up)

So why can I communicate via shell but not via browser, what am I missing here? Should my browser not just forward the GET request to port 12345?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've confused the source port and destination port.

`$ nc -p 12345 google.com 80`

This command tells netcat to open a connection with the server google.com on their remote port, 80, from your source port 12345.

In contrast, localhost:12345 specifies the remote port to be 12345 and the source port could be whatever your operating system happens to allocate for the request.  This would be akin to google.com:80 in your first example.

The source port does not respond to requests for new connections as there are no services listening to answer requests addressed to it.

EDIT: Further reading on source vs. destination port can be found at https://superuser.com/questions/704742/source-address-source-port-vs-destination-address-destination-port

EDIT 2:  If you just want to make HTTP requests and force your local port, check out cURL.  The following will do what you want.

`$ curl --local-port 12345 google.com:80`

You cannot make a modern browser use a specific port because of a lot of factors, including parallel requests and pipelined requests.  Basically, each time you load a webpage, there could be dozens of requests open simultaneously on dozens of ports.  The web is more complex than it used to be, and specifying a single port to load a page has no practical meaning because of the many simultaneous connections that trigger when you visit a page.

Comment: thank you, so that means I  basically can't make my browser to use the TCP connection, the way I wanted it here?

Comment: If you want to observe traffic between your computer and google.com:80 all you have to do is go to google in a browser and in WireShark, choose your external wireless adapter.  The source port is irrelevant if you're just looking to do some packet capture.

Comment: Yes , I understand that, I just wanted to know if I can make my browser use a specific TCP connection for that request, e.g. make it use a local port I defined. I realise it's not really necessary for anything.